# Underline :after effect leave a pixel even when width go back to 0px

Tags: css

this is my code:

```
 .menu_item::after{
            content: "";
            display: block;
            background-color: black !important;
            width: 0px;
            height: 2px;
            transition: width 0.5s;
        }
        
 .menu_item:hover::after{
            width: 100%;
        }
        
 .menu_item.active::after{
            width: 100%;
        }
```

It simply make a underline-like effect transition by make the width of the ::after content go from 0 to 100%, so indeed when the mouse leave the .menu_item the width go back from 100% to 0.
The problem is, the underline stay on 1px for some seconds after it goes back from 100% to 0px, and it's very unpleasant to see.
Is there something i can do or it's a thing i have to keep?

[The problem appears under "Qualcosa su di me"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01G2i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just changed the color of the background-color of the .menu_item as the bg-color of the container, and added that to the transition:

```
        .menu_item::after{
            content: "";
            display: block;
            background-color: RGBA(190, 0, 40, 0);
            width: 0px;
            height: 2px;
            transition: width 0.5s, background-color 0.7s;
        }
        
        .menu_item:hover::after{
            background-color: black;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .menu_item.active::after{
            background-color: black;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Doing so make it go "invisible" before displaying that 1px